# Probabilistic Turing machine - Probability that the head has moved k steps to the right on the work tape

Tags: turing-machines, probabilistic-turing-machines

I have a PTM with following transition:

$\delta(Z_0, \square , 0) = \delta(Z_0, \square , L, R)$,

$\delta(Z_0, \square , 1) = \delta(Z_0, \square , R, R)$

Suppose that this PTM executes n steps. What is the probability that the head
has moved k steps to the right on the work tape (in total, i.e., k is the difference
between moves to the right and moves to the left) ?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Help us help you: what have you done so far? what is unclear?  what are your thoughts on the problem? We're not a "do my problems for me" site.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me as first thought, it is the summation of all moves i to R, j to L where
( i+j = n) AND (i - j = k) which leads to
i =(n+k) /2

Assuming the prob of each step of the walk is indep. from the current position (I can't read the probs u r writing, the 2nd parameter is appearing as a square). So, it would be something like

Pij= (PR ^ i) * (PL ^ j)

Ps

(I'm talking probability, I do not have a fresh memory of  Probabilistic Turing m/cs at the moment)